# Python Jupyter - sklearn categories_feature giving error

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

I have below code in the Jupyter notebook, I think Sklearn categories_feature function is no longer available and giving me the error. What to use instead of categories_feature. I am very new to Machine Learning and python so any help would be appreciated.

```
def encode_data(X_full,y_full,required_column,label_columns,onehot_columns):
    X=X_full.copy()
    y=y_full.copy()

    X=X[required_column]

    #Encode categorical text values to mumbers

    for i in label_columns:
        labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
        X[i] = labelencoder.fit_transform(X[i])
    labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
    y["RENEWAL_STATUS"] = labelencoder.fit_transform(y["RENEWAL_STATUS"])

    #Encode categorical numbers to columns to better represent categories. 
    onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories_feature = onehot_columns)
    X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
    y = y.values
```

The error message is :

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categories_feature'
```

Comment: I think you should use just `categories` instead of `categories_feature`. So, your one-hot encoder should be: `OneHotEncoder(categories = onehot_columns)`

Comment: if I use categories I am getting below error                                                                         ValueError: Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, it has to be of shape (n_features,).

Comment: Make sure `onhot_columns` is of `(n_features,)` shape. If not, check other functions responsible for creating `onhot_columns`